# how to solve Improperly Configuation error in django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, crud

I am developing a crud application using django,using Class based views, Create and retrieve functions are working properly but detail function don't here is my code snippets

**Error**
  [image]

**views.py**

```
class Details(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'user_details'
    model = models.CreateUser
    template_name = 'main/detail_form.html'
```

**Models.py**

```
   class CreateUser(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
       age = models.IntegerField()
       email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
       gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('main:create', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$', views.Create.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'allUsers/$', views.UsersList.as_view(), name='allUsers'),
    url(r'^allUsers/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
]
```

**main/urls.py**

```
path(r'user/', include('main.urls'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Details` view class instead of `DetailView` generic class in urls.py:

```
url(r'^allUsers/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Details.as_view(), name='detail')
```